# Custom routing PHP

Tags: php, routes, preg-match

I'm trying out some custom php routing, and something is wrong at the last line of this function:

```
public function is_valid_uri($a){
 $s=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 return (preg_match('/'.$a.'/i',$s))?true:false;
}
```

I'm testing it using:

```
die($route->is_valid_uri("\/u\/u\/?[0-9]*"));
```

What's the problem? If the uri is incorrect, it should return false. It returns nothing at all, just dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var_dump($route->is_valid_uri("\/u\/u\/?[0-9]*"));
die();
```

If you just print a boolean and it's "false", PHP will print an empty string instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was dumb enough to test it with only non-matching URIs. I thought there was something with the regular expression :).